# TypeScript: how to call a custom utli JS function from TypeScript class

Tags: javascript, typescript

EXAMPLE: 
JS utilities function like so :

```
BDA.Utils.formatString = function (string) {
 (....)
 return someFormattedStr;
}
```

now I want to call this from my TS class, like so:

```
export class Building {
    image: string;

    get getFormatted(): string {
        return BDA.Utils.formatString (this.image);
    }
}
```

I get a warning/error in type script saying that, basically, it does recognize BDA.Utils

is there anyway to make TS ignore this? or define this as interface or something to make it assume that such a thing exists? My main problems is nesting of the modules/classes BDA->Utils

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your code:

```
declare module BDA.Utils {
    function formatString(s: string): string;
}
```